# My app does not recognize JSX when I run babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am following instructions from a React course when setting up Babel with Webpack and now I get this error:

ERROR in ./src/app.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/38164/Desktop/react-course-projects/indecision-app/src/app.js: Unexpected token (4:17)

image of the error

[image: 1]

Here are the files from the setup:
app.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const template = <p>testing</p>;
ReactDOM.render(template, document.getElementById('app'));
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/app.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        loader: "babel-loader",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "indecision-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack --watch",
    "build-babel": "babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=env,react --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "live-server": "^1.2.2",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "3.1.0"
  }
}
```

.babelrs

```js
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

There is probably something minor, but I can't figure it out, as this is new for me.

Comment: Please include code/config as text, not images.

Comment: Sorry about that. I made the changes.

Comment: Try renaming `app.js` to `app.jsx` then change `test: /\.js$/,` to `test: /\.jsx?$/,`